# General Sobolev embedding with $kp=n$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded, open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose $\partial \Omega$ is $C^1$. Assume $kp=n$, $1\le p < \infty$ and $u \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$. Then  $$\lVert u \rVert_{L^q(\Omega)} \le C \lVert u\rVert_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}$$ for all $1\le q < \infty$. The constant $C$ depends only on $n,p,q,\Omega$.

I know the inequality holds for $k=1$. How to extend it to this general case?

Comment: Do you now Sobolev's embedding theorem in the case $k p < n$?

Comment: @gerw  Yes I do. So I should use the result when $kp<n$ to arrive at the theorem when $kp=n$?

Answer (score 1):

For all $q \in [n / (n-k), \infty)$, there is $p' < p$ with
$$
\frac 1q = \frac1{p'} - \frac{k}{n}.$$
Now, you can apply the Sobolev embedding theorem to get
$$ \|u \|_{L^q(\Omega)} \le C \, \|u\|_{W^{k,p'}(\Omega)}.$$
The embeddings for the Lebesgue spaces directly yield
$$ \|u\|_{W^{k,p'}(\Omega)} \le C' \, \|u\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)}.$$
Combining these estimates yields your desired inequality.

The case $q < n/(n-k)$ can be obtained by another application of the embeddings of the Lebesgue spaces.

Comment: Is his/her question still true if $\Omega=\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: No, I don't think so.